# Difference between Singleton implementations

Tags: c++, singleton

So, i found different ways to implement the "creation" of the singleton.
EDIT: When I say "creation", I mean it. This code would be placed in the Singleton::{ctor} or static Singleton::Init() functions of course.

```
//v1
        //the first "1" is casted to a pointer to Ty, then that pointer is casted
        //back to int to obtain the hex address
        //the second 1 is casted to a pointer to Ty, then to a pointer
        //to cSingleton<Ty> because Ty is a derived class and finally
        //back to int to get the hex address
        //after that it's simple pointer arithmetics to get the offset
        int offset = (int)(Ty*)1 - (int)(cSingleton <Ty>*)(Ty*)1;
        m_pSingleton = (Ty*)((int)this + offset);
//v2
        m_pSingleton = static_cast<Ty*>(this);
//v3
        m_pSingleton = (Ty*)this;
```

Is there any significant difference between them?
To my knowledge, v2 and v3 should be the same, but it's v1 I don't really understand. I kinda know what it does, but for what purpose?

Also, please don't turn this into a "Singletons are BAAAAD" discussion.

Comment: WTH is that? Looks like an entry to this contest : www.ioccc.org/main.html

Comment: um. You "create" a singleton by having a static pointer to the class, and then having a static factory function that creates the class, or returns the existing pointer. I don't know what this code is doing, other than a lot of needless and dangerous casts.

Comment: Singleton is supposed to have private constructor(s), that means you cannot have `this` pointer before you have created an instance of the singleton. and if you're already have an instance (of your singleton), then what is the above code doing?

Comment: @abel: Why thank you. :) @Nawaz: like i edited, this is just a snippet out of the ctor or static Init function

Comment: v1 is technically not legal code.  You can't cast arbitrary values to pointers. There are theoretical machines (some still exist I believe) that have special pointer registers that will fault if an invalid address is placed in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Since the question seems to have died, I'll try to answer it on my own.)</sup>
What `v1` does is manually adjusting the `this` pointer to point to the address of the derived object. Normally, `static_cast` or a normal c-style cast does this by itself, but maybe that wasn't the case on earlier compilers or there was a bug. What ever is the case, it does what the casts do.

Answer (score 1):

v2 and v3 are pretty much the same, but v3 is using a c-style cast (c++ style casting is safer, as you get more checks at compile time).

v1 is... wow...  Here's what it's doing:

- cast the number `1` to a pointer of my type `Ty`, and back to an `int`.  I would expect this to still yield `1`.
- cast the number `1` to a pointer of my type `Ty`, cast that to a pointer of `cSingleton<Ty>`, and finally back to an `int`.  I would expect this to also still be `1`.
- subtract the two.  I would expect this to be 0.
- set the singleton to `this`, like in v2 and v3, but adjust for the "offset"

I'm guessing there's some quirk of architecture someplace where the result of casting 1 leads you to a non-1 result, so the offset would be non-zero.  So this would be a way to adjust for casting quirks on a platform.

That's a guess though, and I would hope there would be some comments to explain the code (but probably not).  Maybe someone can chime in with a more concrete answer than mine, but hopefully this gives you something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread58955.html) is a nice singleton C++ example. I have no idea why you're using this kind of coding, this is hardly good practice.

Comment: It's just one example, there are different ways to deal with different scenarios, like multithreading...

Comment: IIRC, that singleton can on occasion screw up.  In that example, you need to use new to create a new instance regardless of the value of `pinstance`.  Once you have the new `*pinstance`, use your platform's (atomic) cmpexchange instruction or compiler intrinsic to test for zero and if zero replace with the new `pinstance`.  If you do not replace `pinstance`, delete it.  There is a paper by Alexandrescu on this subject but I don't remember the name and I couldn't find it.